# How to integrate Ratchet websocket in Symfony 5?

Tags: php, symfony, websocket, ratchet

**Context**

The setup I current have is Symfony 5 API and Ratchet on the backend, on the frontend Vue 2.6 and vue-socket.oi-extended. I'm using Symfony encore, so everything is in one project.

I'm setting up a real time messaging feature.

**Issue**

I'm currently getting a CORS error when a request is emitted on the frontend.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:3001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NYhZwnE' from origin 'https://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**Attempted Fixes**

1. Installing the Symfony cors bundle and tried many different configurations.
2. Setting 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the index.php.
3. Setting the `new OriginCheck()` in Ratchet.

Any assistance is appreciated, please see below my code:

I set up the MessageService as per the Ratchet documentation.

src/service/websocket/MessageService.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Service\Websocket;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class MessageService implements MessageComponentInterface {

  protected $clients;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
}

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
      $this->clients->attach($conn);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
      foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
        if ($from != $client) {
            $client->send($msg);
        }
    }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
      $this->clients->detach($conn);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
      $conn->close();
    }
}
```

Registered the service.

config/services.yaml

```
App\Service\Websocket\:
    resource: '../src/Service/Websocket'
```

I setup a command to start the websocket server.

src/Command/WebsocketServerCommand.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Command;

use App\Service\Websocket\MessageService;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use App\Websocket\MessageHandler;
use Ratchet\Http\OriginCheck;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
 
class WebsocketServerCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = "run:websocket-server";
 
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
      $port = 3001;
      $output->writeln("Starting server on port " . $port);
      
      $messageService = new MessageService();
      $ws = new WsServer($messageService);
      $httpServer = new HttpServer($ws);
      $server = IoServer::factory($httpServer, $port);

      $output->writeln("waiting...");
      $server->run();
      return 0;
    }
}
```

I run the command `php bin/console run:websocket-server` and get the response:

> Starting server on port 3001
> waiting...

The frontend:

main.js (index.js)

```
import VueSocketIOExt from 'vue-socket.io-extended';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:3001');
Vue.use(VueSocketIOExt, socket, { store });
```

Component within `export default`

```
sockets: {
    connect() {
      console.log("socket connected");
    },
  },
```

UPDATE:
I attempted to connect to `ws://127.0.0.1:3001`  from [http://websocket.org/](http://websocket.org/echo.html) which was successful and can broad cast a message.

Therefore, the issue must be with the either the frontend or the cors configuration on the backend.

I added `$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/');` to my index.php

I also ran the Symfony web server on http instead of https.
I uninstalled vue-socket.io-extended and tried vue-socket.io

After every change got the same CORS error. This is bulshit.

Comment: When you connect to http://127.0.0.1:3001, the request is not handled by Symfony web server (and doesn't go though index.php), it is handled by Ratchet webserver, which is started by the `run:websocket-server` command. So you have to adjust your WebsocketServerCommand class somehow

Comment: I thought that too, as I said I tried adding `new OriginCheck()` on the WebsocketServerCommand and set the  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. restarted the WS server and still got the CORS error.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?